# Quickest way to make 3 arrays the same size?

Tags: php

I'm  wondering what is the quickest way to take 3 arrays with an uneven quantity of values and make them even? I need to either slice two arrays or pad two arrays. Padding might work best. I'm trying to put stock market data into a highcharts graph and need the arrays to have the same quantity of values.

For example

```
print_r(count($array1)); //prints 2000
print_r(count($array2)); //prints 1801
print_r(count($array3)); //prints 1951

//The arrays contain stock prices which are floats in this format: 0.00
```

I need $array1 and $array3 to slice off the fat from the bottom and become the size of $array2 (1801). Or I need to pad $array2 and array3 with 0.00 figures until they become the size of $array1. Padding is my first preference.

I'll be doing this dynamically across varying values so need the slicing/padding to be conducted using non-static values.

Comment: are they all indexed the same? 0,1,2,....

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What does "slice off the fat from the bottom" mean? What is the "bottom" of an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty simple, it's worth checking the official PHP documentation first. Assuming you know which array is the largest (let's say it's array1) you can use array_pad.

```
$array2 = array_pad($array2, count($array1), 0);
$array3 = array_pad($array3, count($array1), 0);
```

If you're not sure which is the biggest, a loop over them with count() should be pretty quick and easy.

More info on array_pad: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pad.php

Comment: You're right, that is easy. I should have investigated that a bit more before asking. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

this should work

```
$new_array_1 = []; 
$new_array_3 = []; 

foreach (  $array2 as $key => $value ){
  $new_array_1[] = $array1[$key];
  $new_array_3[] = $array3[$key];
}
```

now all arrays are equal to array 2.